# Dbus: Logout other user

Tags: linux, command-line, session, d-bus

I'm new with dbus. I know how to logout current user from terminal using dbus messages `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1`
It sends messages to SessionManager but currently I'm logged with user B, but switched account with user A(not I'm logged in as A). Now I have 2 session. My goal is to send Dbus messages and logout user B. When I'm typing
 `dbus-send --session           \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
  --type=method_call          \
  --print-reply               \
  /org/freedesktop/DBus       \
  org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames`

It only shows me 1 `string "org.gnome.SessionManager"` which is current users. Is it possible to use dbus messages and accomplish what I want?

Comment: You have to send the message to that user session bus so you'd need to `su -` to that user and use their respective `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and in theory it should work (with side effects maybe, like logging you out too - I'm not sure this would work OK). But why ?

Comment: So there is no way that I can get dbus address of other user?

Comment: There are ways to do that, e.g. if the other user has a nautilus window open you could run as root `sed -nz 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//p' /proc/$(pgrep -U 1001 nautilus)/environ` (where `1001` is the UID) - basically you have to get it from `/proc/$pid/environ` where `$pid` is something unique to that user

Comment: I used `id -u username` return value but it gives me error sayig `sed: can't read /proc//envir: No such file or directory`.

Comment: It's `/proc/$pid/environ` not `envir` and as I said you gotta get the `pid` of an app from that user session... whatever that is...

Comment: Sorry I pasted incorrectly. As I understand dbus-send uses bus name to connect, but how can I connect to sessionmanager of other user and send some messages to it?

Comment: I've just explained above that you _can't_ send messages to another session bus unless you do it as that user and have that session bus address so e.g. `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ToCuEUyLn0,guid=9296df6ba791b044d4236e45545fbe55` then your `dbus` command

Comment: thank you very much :) And one more question please, If I'm logged in as user A and launch a process with the name of B and that process creates session for user B `/etc/X11/Xsession 'gnome-session --session=ubuntu'` is it possible to connect to B's session manager from that process?

Answer (score 0):

From the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287417/dbus-logout-other-user#comment501205_287417):

> you can't send messages to another session bus unless you do it as that user and have that session bus address